# use php command line

Tags: php, python

Like the way we can use python in command line from its command line interpreter in order to test whether small code snippets are fine or not, how can I do the same with PHP (or can I)?

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:22:14) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "abc"
abc
>>>

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4>php -a
Interactive mode enabled
```

doesn't give me php prompt

can someone show an example on how do have an interactive shell in php.

Answer (score 3):

The PHP Manual has a section on [command line usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).

There's also details on an [interactive shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am aware of this link but I was looking for an interactive shell that we get in python. Is there a way I can use a similar interactive shell in php. something like when I write echo "Hello World!", it instantly prints "Hello World"

Comment: I looked into that.. It doesn't work.. (check my updated post)